# Python Create dummy variables based on day of week in double index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dayofweek, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe with a double index (day, time) and would like to create new columns 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' etc equal to one if the index day is in the correct day.

My original dataframe:

```
                       Visitor  
Date       Time                                                              
2017-09-11 4:45           0         
           5:00           1        
           5:15          26       
....
2017-09-12 4:45           0       
           5:00           1         
           5:15          26     
....
```

What I would like to have:

```
                       Visitor      Monday    Tuesday
Date       Time                                                              
2017-09-11 4:45           0           1          0
           5:00           1           1          0
           5:15          26           1          0
....
2017-09-12 4:45           0           0          1
           5:00           1           0          1
           5:15          26           0          1
....
```

Here is what I tried:

```
df['Monday'] = (df.index.get_level_values(0).weekday() == 0)
```

However I get an error saying "'Int64Index' object is not callable".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need remove `()` from :

```
df['Monday'] = (df.index.get_level_values(0).weekday == 0).astype(int)

print (df)
                 Visitor  Monday
Date       Time                 
2017-09-11 4:45        0       1
           5:00        1       1
           5:15       26       1
2017-09-12 4:45        0       0
           5:00        1       0
           5:15       26       0
```

---

```
names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

for i, x in enumerate(names):
    df[x] = (df.index.get_level_values(0).weekday == i).astype(int)
print (df)
                 Visitor  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  \
Date       Time                                                          
2017-09-11 4:45        0       1        0          0         0       0   
           5:00        1       1        0          0         0       0   
           5:15       26       1        0          0         0       0   
2017-09-12 4:45        0       0        1          0         0       0   
           5:00        1       0        1          0         0       0   
           5:15       26       0        1          0         0       0   

                 Saturday  Sunday  
Date       Time                    
2017-09-11 4:45         0       0  
           5:00         0       0  
           5:15         0       0  
2017-09-12 4:45         0       0  
           5:00         0       0  
           5:15         0       0
```

Another solution is a improved another original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46219664/1) - need [`DatetimeIndex.weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday_name.html) with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by original index and if necessary add reindex for add missig names:

```
names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

df1 = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.index.get_level_values(0).weekday_name)
                .set_index(df.index).reindex(columns=names, fill_value=0))
print (df1)
                 Visitor  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  \
Date       Time                                                          
2017-09-11 4:45        0       1        0          0         0       0   
           5:00        1       1        0          0         0       0   
           5:15       26       1        0          0         0       0   
2017-09-12 4:45        0       0        1          0         0       0   
           5:00        1       0        1          0         0       0   
           5:15       26       0        1          0         0       0   

                 Saturday  Sunday  
Date       Time                    
2017-09-11 4:45         0       0  
           5:00         0       0  
           5:15         0       0  
2017-09-12 4:45         0       0  
           5:00         0       0  
           5:15         0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_dummies` with `weekday_name`

```
In [293]: df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.index.get_level_values(0).weekday_name)
                    .set_index(df.index))
Out[293]:
                 Visitor  Monday  Tuesday
Date       Time
2017-09-11 4:45        0       1        0
           5:00        1       1        0
           5:15       26       1        0
2017-09-12 4:45        0       0        1
           5:00        1       0        1
           5:15       26       0        1

In [272]: pd.get_dummies(df.index.get_level_values(0).weekday_name)
Out[272]:
   Monday  Tuesday
0       1        0
1       1        0
2       1        0
3       0        1
4       0        1
5       0        1
```

Details

```
In [286]: df.index.get_level_values(0).weekday_name
Out[286]: Index([u'Monday', u'Monday', u'Monday', u'Tuesday', u'Tuesday', u'Tuesday'], dtype='object', name=u'Date')
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked perfectly as well! :)