# Create dummy values for a list of dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe with a double index (day, time) and would like to create a new column 'Holiday' equal to one if the index day belongs to a list of holidays.

My list of holidays of type DatetimeIndex:

```
holidays = ['2017-09-11', '2017-12-24']
```

My original dataframe:

```
                       Visitor  
Date       Time                                                              
2017-09-11 4:45           0         
           5:00           1        
           5:15          26       
....
2017-09-12 4:45           0       
           5:00           1         
           5:15          26     
....
```

What I would like to have:

```
                       Visitor      Holiday  
Date       Time                                                              
2017-09-11 4:45           0           1         
           5:00           1           1         
           5:15          26           1         
....
2017-09-12 4:45           0           0         
           5:00           1           0         
           5:15          26           0        
....
```

Here is what I tried based on this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219575/6404688):

```
df['Holiday'] = int(df.index.get_level_values(0) in holidays == True)
```

However my column 'Holiday' always has the value 0...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isin` by taking the date level from `get_level_values` and use `astype(int)` to convert boolean to integer.

```
In [192]: df['Holiday'] = df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(holidays).astype(int)

In [193]: df
Out[193]:
                 Visitor  Holiday
Date       Time
2017-09-11 4:45        0        1
           5:00        1        1
           5:15       26        1
2017-09-12 4:45        0        0
           5:00        1        0
           5:15       26        0
```

---

If you want a copy instead of modifying `df`

```
In [196]: df.assign(Holiday=df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(holidays).astype(int))
Out[196]:
                 Visitor  Holiday
Date       Time
2017-09-11 4:45        0        1
           5:00        1        1
           5:15       26        1
2017-09-12 4:45        0        0
           5:00        1        0
           5:15       26        0
```

Comment: You're lucky it's me and not someone else with an identical solution to yours who posted literally seconds before you did. ;-)

Comment: Hmm, somewhere I feel np.where is quite not same as astype(int), and obviously we both were independently at the `isin` part, what was it <30secs?

Comment: @Batmax You can upvote both solutions, they're essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution should actually throw a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Note that the `in` operator is meant for scalar values and is not meant to be used with pandas dataframes. pandas instead has a lot of conditional and bitwise operators that are overloaded, as well as a comprehensive suite of APIs for the purpose of conditional and boolean logic.

---

You can use *`np.where`* and *`isin`*.

```
df['Holiday'] = np.where(df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(holidays), 1, 0)
df


                 Visitor  Holiday
Date       Time                  
2017-09-11 4:45        0        1
           5:00        1        1
           5:15       26        1
2017-09-12 4:45        0        0
           5:00        1        0
           5:15       26        0
```